# Can Windows Explorer's search-as-you-type speed be modified?

Tags: windows-explorer, search

What I'm referring to, is in Windows/File Explorer, if I were to type a letter, "B" for example, it would jump to the first available file/folder starting with a "B".

Then, if I was fast enough, I might be able to type "BO", which would then jump to the first file/folder starting with a "BO".

My question is, what are the requirements of being able to search this way, and what speed does it allow? For example, does it allow a user to type each letter with a window:

```
"B" (wait .2 seconds) "O" (wait .2 seconds).....
```

Or does it have a window in which you can type your input:

```
(.5 second window start) "BO" (.5 second window end)
```

Is this setting changeable?

Comment: I've never come across a registry setting for this. Best I know it's hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

The delay (timed here) is 1 second after the last letter was typed, or until it no longer matches, where it default beeps.
If you delay by one second, the next letter typed will start a new search.
 Tapping the ESC key also begins a new search

I have two files:

> ABC Connect fixes - All.zip
>   ABC Connect fixes.zip

if I start typing `ABC...` and take 5 seconds (which is pretty darn slow) to get to the end of `fixes` before hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> it will still jump from the first file to the next.

The location (if any) that this could be adjusted in the registry is not known  (general web and MS searching). it could be part of the autocomplete autosuggest stuff for the explorer which does have some registry settings, but not timings.